# PuTTY/ZOC/SecureCRT equivalent for Linux

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

I've managed to configure the GNOME Terminal to launch an ssh command that connects to my remote host, but that feels hacky.

What open source terminal emulators for Linux support

- host profiles with:

  - SSH key login
  - customizable background color
  - customizable font size
- configurable keyboard shortcuts to switch among tabs (Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn, which switch tabs in Chrome).

I don't really care about complex layout features like those in Terminator, if I can't easily create a host profile.

Comment: Uhm... PuTTY? http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: @mustaccio: PuTTY doesn't support tabs. I'm also looking for [ZMODEM support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35986/open-source-ssh-terminal-client-for-linux-with-zmodem-support/39732).